# How do I properly Synchronize the data displayed in a ViewModel with the data the Model is providing when using Collections

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm currently trying to develop a litte WPF Application using MVVM and caliburn.micro.
The Problem is now the following situation

```
class ExampleModel
{
   List<string> Names { get; set; }
}

class ExampleViewModel : Screen 
{
   public ExampleViewModel(ExampleModel model)
   {
       peopleNames = new ObservableCollection<string>(model.Names);
   }

   private ObservableCollection<string> peopleNames;
   public ObservableCollection<string> PeopleNames
   {
      get => peopleNames;
   }
}
```

If I know access the peopleNames List in the view everything is allright. I can manipulate the data an so forth. What I'm missing is the connection between the Model and the ViewModel.

What possibilities are there to connect the model to the viewModel-property and what is the correct way to handle this? (I've some ideas and would like to get your opinion on them)

Suggestion 1:

```
  // when the view is closed or a specific 'saving' action is called I update the model by doing sth. like:
  model.Names = new List<string>(PeopleNames);
```

Suggestion 2:

```
  // I bind directly to the model:
   public List<string> PeopleNames
   {
      get => model.Names;
      set
      {
         model.Names = value;
         NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => PeopleNames);
      }
   }
```

Don't restrict your answers to my suggestions - a best practice would be my favourite :)

Comment: The second way won't do if you want to update the collection using the view - because the list has no `CollectionChanged` event.

Comment: Yeah, thats right. I would have to inform the view manually. :/

Comment: Your question is too broad, having many different possible answers. However, you can look at using the `BindingList<T>` class instead of `ObservableCollection<T>`. That class doesn't just copy from a source list, but actually uses the source list as the underlying list. As long as modifications to the underlying list are done through the `BindingList<T>` instance (i.e. through the UI), everything will stay in sync.

Comment: Okay, I will have a look at BindingLists :) It sounds like this could be what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have run into this issue myself a couple times, and have made some helper classes that "synchronize" two collections. They support one-way and two-way synchronization as well as conversion.

Here's the full code:

```
public abstract class CollectionSyncronizer<T1, T2>
{
    public bool IsSyncronized { get; protected set; }               

    public abstract void Syncronize();

    protected void Update<TColl, TSource, TTarget>(TColl targetCollectionToBeUpdated, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e, Dictionary<TSource, TTarget> mapFromSourceToTarget, Func<TSource, TTarget> targetItemsGenerator) where TColl : IList<TTarget>
    {            
        switch (e.Action)
        {
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                {
                    foreach (TSource sourceItem in e.NewItems)
                    {
                        var targetItem = targetItemsGenerator(sourceItem);
                        mapFromSourceToTarget.Add(sourceItem, targetItem);

                        targetCollectionToBeUpdated.Add(targetItem);
                    }
                }
                break;

            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
                {
                    foreach (TSource removedSourceItem in e.OldItems)
                    {
                        targetCollectionToBeUpdated.Remove(mapFromSourceToTarget[removedSourceItem]);
                        mapFromSourceToTarget.Remove(removedSourceItem);
                    }
                }
                break;

            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace:
                {
                    int i = 0;
                    foreach (TSource newSourceItem in e.NewItems)
                    {
                        var newTargetItem = targetItemsGenerator(newSourceItem);
                        mapFromSourceToTarget.Add(newSourceItem, newTargetItem);

                        targetCollectionToBeUpdated[e.NewStartingIndex + i] = newTargetItem;
                        i += 1;
                    }
                    foreach (TSource oldSourceItem in e.OldItems)
                    {
                        mapFromSourceToTarget.Remove(oldSourceItem);
                    }
                }
                break;

            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Move:
                {
                    targetCollectionToBeUpdated.RemoveAt(e.OldStartingIndex);
                    targetCollectionToBeUpdated.Insert(e.NewStartingIndex, mapFromSourceToTarget[(TSource)e.NewItems[0]]);
                }
                break;

            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset:
                {
                    targetCollectionToBeUpdated.Clear();
                }
                break;
        }            
    }
}

public class OneWayCollectionSyncronizer<TSourceColl, TTargColl, TSource, TTarg> : CollectionSyncronizer<TSource, TTarg> where TSourceColl : INotifyCollectionChanged where TTargColl : IList<TTarg>
{        
    private readonly Dictionary<TSource, TTarg> _mapFromSourceToTarget = new Dictionary<TSource, TTarg>();        
    private readonly Func<TSource, TTarg> _newTargetItemFromSource;        

    public OneWayCollectionSyncronizer(TSourceColl sourceCollection, TTargColl targetCollection, Func<TSource, TTarg> newTargetItemFromSource)
    {
        SourceCollection = sourceCollection;
        TargetCollection = targetCollection;            
        _newTargetItemFromSource = newTargetItemFromSource;
    }

    public EventHandler TargetCollectionHasBeenUpdated;

    public TSourceColl SourceCollection { get; }

    public TTargColl TargetCollection { get; }        

    public override void Syncronize()
    {
        if (!IsSyncronized)
        {
            SourceCollection.CollectionChanged += UpdateTarget;

            IsSyncronized = true;
        }            
    }

    private void UpdateTarget(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Update(TargetCollection, e, _mapFromSourceToTarget, _newTargetItemFromSource);
        TargetCollectionHasBeenUpdated?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }        
}

public class TwoWayCollectionSyncronizer<TColl1, TColl2, T1, T2> : CollectionSyncronizer<T1, T2> where TColl1 : INotifyCollectionChanged, IList<T1> where TColl2 : INotifyCollectionChanged, IList<T2>
{
    private readonly Dictionary<T1, T2> _mapFromFirstToSecond = new Dictionary<T1, T2>();
    private readonly Dictionary<T2, T1> _mapFromSecondToFirst = new Dictionary<T2, T1>();
    private readonly Func<T1, T2> _newSecondItemFromFirst;
    private readonly Func<T2, T1> _newFirstItemFromSecond;

    public TwoWayCollectionSyncronizer(TColl1 firstCollection, TColl2 secondCollection, Func<T1, T2> newSecondItemFromFirst, Func<T2, T1> newFirstItemFromSecond)
    {
        FirstCollection = firstCollection;
        SecondCollection = secondCollection;
        _newFirstItemFromSecond = newFirstItemFromSecond;
        _newSecondItemFromFirst = newSecondItemFromFirst;
    }

    public EventHandler FirstCollectionHasBeenUpdated;

    public EventHandler SecondCollectionHasBeenUpdated;

    public TColl1 FirstCollection { get; }

    public TColl2 SecondCollection { get; }        

    public override void Syncronize()
    {
        if (!IsSyncronized)
        {
            SecondCollection.CollectionChanged += UpdateFirst;
            FirstCollection.CollectionChanged += UpdateSecond;

            IsSyncronized = true;
        }            
    }

    private void UpdateFirst(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        FirstCollection.CollectionChanged -= UpdateSecond;

        Update(FirstCollection, e, _mapFromSecondToFirst, _newFirstItemFromSecond);
        FirstCollectionHasBeenUpdated?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);

        FirstCollection.CollectionChanged += UpdateSecond;
    }

    private void UpdateSecond(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        SecondCollection.CollectionChanged -= UpdateFirst;

        Update(SecondCollection, e, _mapFromFirstToSecond, _newSecondItemFromFirst);
        SecondCollectionHasBeenUpdated?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);

        SecondCollection.CollectionChanged += UpdateFirst;
    }
}
```

The classes basically serve as a "bridge" between two collection, listening to relevant events and updating things accordingly. Usage is as follows:

```
var syncronizer = new TwoWayCollectionSyncronizer(modelCollection, viewModelCollection, x => x, x => x);
syncronizer.Syncronize();
```

Comment: So you still differentiate between your two collections (to be able to use observ. coll. 
 in VM and normal coll. in the model) but you synchronize them at distinct points in your application using your synchronizer?

Comment: Mmm, I guess so, if I understand you correctly. I mean, you kind of have to, if you are using the "conversion" functionality (this is the case if you want to wrap your model objects, a common scenario). Now, what collection to use is down to the synchronization direction: "the source" _has_ to implement INotifyCollectionChanged, and "the target" - lList<T>.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your replay I'll try your solution to my problem. But I'm wondering why this isn't a bigger issue with a given best practice because I think this should happen much more often.